# Directory scoped typedef files and exported modules that implement their types

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I've imported and defined a type `Match` over the directory `foo` by adding it to a `typedef.js` file in `foo`'s root.

A function exported from `foo` which passively uses that type is imported in `bar.js` in another directory. However, `bar.js` can't resolve that type properly, only displaying its path instead of its name.

```
├── foo/
│   ├── typedef.js
│   ├─- foo.js
│   └── util/
│         └── match.js
└── bar.js
```

```js
// foo/typedef.js

/** @typedef {import('./util/match').Match} Match */
```

```js
// foo.js

/**
 * @param {Match} m Type not imported, but resolves because of the local typedef
 */
export default function foo(m) {}
```

```js
// bar.js

import foo from './foo/foo'

foo() // Match doesn't resolve, instead shows "./util/match"
```

`Match` resolves if I:

- Import the type in `foo.js`
- Define it in an common `typedef` that covers `bar.js`

This makes sense, since importing `foo` defines any imported types, otherwise `Match` doesn't exist as far as `bar.js` is concerned. But I'm curious as to how scoped types are implemented in practice. It feels cumbersome to have to import a type that's already defined in a parent `typedef` and I can't imagine libraries having to go through that.

My main exposure to TS is through `JSDoc` but I'm wondering how libraries handle scoped types similar to `typedefs.js`, do they import relevant types for relevant modules/functions meant to be exported. Are scooed/global types even used in practice?

I'm tagging Typescript because the main concept/functionality should be similar between it and JSDoc regarding scoping (at least because VSCode, which I use and demonstrates this issue, uses TS for JSDoc)

Comment: In TS there is a hack to `T & unknown`, then `T` will be immediately resolved. Try that.